# Vertical spacing of block elements

Tags: html, css

I'm arranging a couple of block level elements next to an image and have used the following HTML/CSS to position everything:

```
<style>
#logo p {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 220px;
    margin-top: -27px;
}

#logo img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}

#logo #a {
    padding-top: 43px;
}
</style>

<div id="logo">
  <p id="a">Label A</p>
  <p id="b">Label B</p>
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/IBM_logo.svg/200px-IBM_logo.svg.png" />
</div>
```

(Editable version here: http://jsfiddle.net/49cAv/1/)

To get the two P elements closer I've used a combination of `margin-top: -27px;` and `padding-top: 43px;` which seems a bit clunky.

Is there a better / cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Hint: use float:left and no absolute positioning

Comment: Wish this was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

**html**

```
<div id="logo">
    <div id="imgCont">
     <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/IBM_logo.svg/200px-IBM_logo.svg.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="labelCont">
      <p id="a">Label A</p>
        <span style="clear:left"></span>
      <p id="b">Label B</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**css**

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#logo p {
    font-size: 24px;
}

#logo img {
    position: relative;
}

#imgCont{
    float:left;
}

#labelCont{
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49cAv/6/)