# Vertical spacing of Heading tags

Tags: html, css

How do you control the space above / below H tags? For example, I'd like two H elements to be vertically centred next to a logo with minimal spacing between them.

I've tried playing around with `margin`, `padding` and `line-height` but it doesn't seem quite satisfactory. For example:

**CSS**

```
img { 
    float: left; 
}
h1 {
    line-height: 0;
    padding-top: 32px;
}
h2 {
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/IBM_logo.svg/200px-IBM_logo.svg.png" />
  <h1 id="a">Label A</h1>
  <h2 id="b">Label B</h2>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49cAv/19/

Any better ways of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025205/vertical-spacing-of-block-elements/24025401#24025401 ?

Comment: Your problem is that you didn't [clear your float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float). So, position properties aren't going to work correctly since you don't have a new block formatting context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align` and `float` do not go along.

`Vertical-align` can be used inside a `td` (or display alike), or upon the `baseline` , or in between inline-boxes.

If you wrap , titles inside an element displayed as an inline-boxe aside another inline-box, then , you can `vertical-align` them to each other :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/49cAv/9/)**

```
.valgn {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
#logo h1, #logo h2 {
    margin:0;
}
```

For this markup:

```
<div id="logo">
    <img class="valgn" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/IBM_logo.svg/200px-IBM_logo.svg.png" />
    <div class="valgn">
         <h1 id="a">Label A</h1>
         <h2 id="b">Label B</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice:*To validate the structure, the image could be wrap into a div.valign too.*

Comment: What do you mean by 'validate the structure'?